# How do i continuously check for commands in c#?

Tags: c#, command, prompt

i imagine something like this:

```
prompt> checkprice
price of foo is 42$
prompt>
```

To run multiple commands.

Comment: If you don't know how to word it properly, imagine how hard can be understanding your issue for me and others...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
while(true) {
    Console.Write("prompt>");
    var command = Console.ReadLine();

    if (command == "command1") doSomething();
    else if (command == "command2") doSomethingElse();
    ...
    else if (command == "quit") break;
}
```

Comment: Why use an additional `else if`? You could just do `while ((command = Console.ReadLine().ToLower()) != "quit") {` (which means you must declare `command` before the loop). --- Also, `.ToLower()` for case-insensitive commands.

Comment: @visualvincent Yes, you could do that. I personally don't like it because 1) you have to declare command outside the loop (and therefore outside its real scope)  2) it somehow is not very readable.

Comment: **1)** Point. Although it doesn't matter much. **2)** I think it gets more readable that way. ;) -- **Though** `.ToLower()` is still good to use so that your program will still execute your commands even if you type `QUIT` or `qUiT`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Do while until type a specific command like "exit":

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    var line = System.Console.ReadLine().Trim();

    while(line!="exit") {
        myOperationCommand(line);
        line = System.Console.ReadLine().Trim(); // read input again
    }

    System.Console.WriteLine("End!\n");
}

// Do some operation...
static void myOperationCommand(string line) {
    switch(line) {
        case "checkprice":
            System.Console.WriteLine("price of foo is 42$");
            break;
        default: 
            System.Console.WriteLine("Command not reconized: " + line);
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this

```
//this is your price variable
static int price = 42;
//function to check it
static void CheckPrice()
{
    Console.WriteLine("price of foo " + price + "$");
}
static void Main()
{
    bool exit = false;
    do
    {
        //write at begin ">"
        Console.Write(">");
        //wait for user input
        string input = Console.ReadLine();
        // if input is "checkprice"
        if (input == "checkprice") CheckPrice();
        if (input == "exit") exit = true;
    } while (!exit);
}
```